# Symfony 4 - PHPUnit - Difficults with the setUp() method

Tags: php, symfony, testing, installation, phpunit

I'm following the Symfony Cast Stripe formation. They use Symfony 3 and I use Symfony 4.

I try to make some test like in the formation : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stripe-level2/testing-webhooks#play

But when I run the test, I've this error :

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare static
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::$container as non
>   static App\Tests\Controller\WebhookControllerTest::$container in
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\StripeFormation2\tests\Controller\WebhookControllerTest.php
>   on  line 11

I made this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use DateTime;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Subscription;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class WebhookControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $em;
    private $container;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }
    // ...
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Change  `private $container;` to  `public static $container;`

Answer (score 3):

since symfony 4.0, the container was already present in the `KernelTestCase` which `WebTestCase` extends. See [git repo](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L36). Compare to [git repo](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/v3.4.34/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L24).

So, in symfony 4, you do not need `$this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();` since it's already declared as `static` in `KernelTestCase`.

If you need to use the container, you could do `self::$container->get('serviceId');`

Answer (score 1):

Please change the variable name `$container` to any other name e.g `$appContainer`. Just as the error message says. `It cannot redeclare $container` and that is because `$container` has been previously declared in the parent class your extending as a static variable.

This will solve your problem.